# Долго выполняется скрипт при подключении к MYSQL удаленно

Tags: php, mysql, centos

Есть 3 сервера :2 донора и 1 акцептор.
Акцептор подключается к базе удаленно , берет данные и обрабатывает скриптом php .
При подключении к базе донора 1  - скрипт работает 10 секунд.
При подключении к базе донора 2  - скрипт работает 50 секунд.
Объем данных одинаковый.

Подскажите, в каком конфиге донора 2 ковыряться и что искать, чтобы не замедлялась скорость  ?
centos 7

Comment: Структура таблиц полностью одинакова ? Содержимое данных сильно похоже ? Engine у таблиц одинаков ? БД выбирает одинаковые планы выполнения для запросов ? Количество ОЗУ выделенное mysql одинаково (смотреть разные переменные буферов в my.cnf относящихся к тому Engine на котором сделаны таблицы). Железо по процессору и главное, по скорости дисков одинаково ? Скорость сети до обоих серверов одинакова ? Ну и еще пара десятков таких вопросов, после ответов на которые можно примерно начать подходить к пониманию почему скорость может отличаться. А потом еще сотня вопросов и разных настроек

Comment: да, все идентично, кроме настройки серверов (сервера куплены у разных хостеров). 
Если не использовать удаленное подключение, а попробовать использовать локально на каждом сервере, то ограничение по скорости пропадает . 
Я погуглил чуток, нашел какой-то параметр `skip-name-resolve`, но к сожалению мне не помогло

Comment: А если разместить на обоих хостерах статичный файл одного размера и попробовать его скачать, он загрузиться с одинаковой скоростью ? Что то больно похоже на скорость сети

Comment: загрузил на оба сервера 150 мб файл. Скачалось практически одинаково по вермени +-1сек. тут какое-то ограничение MYSQL наверно

Comment: Как объем данных меряете ? Количество записей не показатель, сами записи могут сильно отличаться по длине (ну это конечно от природы данных зависит, могут и не отличаться)

Comment: подключитесь с сервера на котором обработка к mysql обоих серверов из консоли mysql и выполните скажем `select count(1) from (тут-запрос-что-работает-сейчас-в-скрипте) x` оно выполниться одинаково быстро

Comment: потом можно запускать скрипт и с помощью какого нибудь iftop смотреть скорость передачи данных на сетевой карте (`-f host ip-адрес` поможет мерять только величину потока  до конкретного сервера). Заодно убедитесь что он например качает данные все время пока работает скрипт (ну или не все время, но примерно одинаково для обоих серверов)